# Shopify with custom digital licensing

Tags: shopify

I am looking to build an online storefront that will contain digital software which requires licenses to activate.

I'm curious if there's some sort of process after purchase/checkout in Shopify (perhaps through an ability to tie into our company's internal API to retrieve a license and assign it to a product id), then present this to the user through email or on Shopify's checkout/download link directly?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a very common pattern in Shopify. When a customer purchases a product, you can hook up some scripting code to inspect the order. When you find a case of needing to issue a license, the script can ask your system (via an API) for a license and send it to the customer however you want (via email for example). There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: This sounds fairly obvious, but is there documentation about this sort of thing in Shopify? I've been told that they have an "API", but how exactly can I call into some javascript or what-have-you after the customer orders software off my shop? If I can figure that out, then I'd be able to send emails like you said from our end... I just don't see how this communication is setup.

Comment: Shopify offers a ton of documentation. Everything is built on the basics. HTML, JS, CSS. The pattern of use for Shopify is the same as for any web service, so there is a gluttony of available info here, there and everywhere.